# How do I start a RabbitMQ node?

Tags: rabbitmq

I keep getting this error every time I try to do something with RabbitMQ:

```
attempted to contact: [fdbvhost@FORTE]

fdbvhost@FORTE:
  * connected to epmd (port 4369) on FORTE
  * epmd reports: node 'fdbvhost' not running at all
                  no other nodes on FORTE
  * suggestion: start the node

current node details:
- node name: 'rabbitmq-cli-54@FORTE'
- home dir: C:\Users\Jesus
- cookie hash: iuRlQy0F81aBpoY9aQqAzw==
```

This is the output I get when I run `rabbitmqctl -n fdbvhost status` or `/rabbitmqctl -n fdbvhost list_vhosts`.

I've tried `rabbitmqctl -n fdbvhost start` which gives me the following output:

```
Error: could not recognise command
Usage:
rabbitmqctl [-n <node>] [-t <timeout>] [-q] <command> [<command options>]
...
```

So this doesn't start it. I cannot find anything about starting a node in the documentation. How do I actually start my node/vhost?

Comment: Did you get the error you've pasted when you ran `rabbitmqctl -n fdbvhost start`, or did that give you some other output?

Comment: That gave me other output. Anything else I try to do, however, such as `rabbitmqctl -n fdbvhost status` seems to give me the error above.

Comment: OK, so *what* other output? Please can you [edit] the question to include that? Also, some examples of what "anything else" and "among other things" mean might be useful.

Comment: Edited with a bit more info and less ambiguous language.

Comment: Have you tried `start_app` instead of `start`, as documented here? http://www.rabbitmq.com/man/rabbitmqctl.1.man.html

Answer (score 18):

Try running the following command from the RabbitMQ's installation sbin directory

```
rabbitmq-server start -detached
```

This should start the broker node if it was stopped for some reason.

Answer (score 2):

Check if you have RabbitMQ installed as a service in the `/etc/init.d/` folder

```
sudo su # might be needed
cd /etc/init.d/
ls . | grep rabbit
```

The output should be `rabbitmq-server`

If that's the case, then, try restarting your service with:

```
sudo service rabbitmq-server restart
```

Answer (score 0):

### For mac users

To Start

```
brew services start rabbitmq
```

To Restart

```
brew services restart rabbitmq
```

To Stop

```
brew services stop rabbitmq
```

To Know the status of the server

```
brew services info rabbitmq
```